# Should I use dried or fresh chilli/ginger in chai tea?

Tags: flavor, tea, herbs, chai

Well, the question is in the title really. What are the pros/cons? I'm making some concentrate by cooking it for a long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how they are dried.  Though if they're properly dehydrated or freeze-dried then you're just rehydrating them in the tea and they'll taste ok.

**Ginger:** I prefer fresh ginger and find that there are some taste notes that aren't present in the dried tea, it makes more pleasant with fresh ginger, but it's more work.

**Chili**: While I haven't tried fresh chili in tea, I'd imagine dried would work better and you wouldn't get interference from oils in the chili.  Also maybe easier to control the amount.

Comment: Ginger actually has some flavor compounds that denature in the drying process to form other flavor compounds. That's why fresh & dried ginger taste so distinctly different.